# Template friend and nested classes

Tags: c++, templates, friend, nested-class

please consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    template <typename S>
    struct bar
    {
        template <typename> friend struct bar;
    };
};
```

I'd like all instantiations of `foo<T>::bar` to be friends of `foo<T>::bar<S>` for any `S`. If `bar` is not a nested template, the syntax above works just fine. But when I do for example

```
int main() 
{  
    foo<int> x;
}
```

MSVC8 (Visual C++ 2005) doesn't like it:

```
1>.\main.cpp(11) : error C3855: 'foo<T>::bar': template parameter 'S' is incompatible with the declaration
1>        .\main.cpp(12) : see reference to class template instantiation 'foo<T>::bar<S>' being compiled
1>        .\main.cpp(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'foo<T>' being compiled
```

The compiler gives me the same errors if I use

```
template <typename> friend struct foo<T>::bar;
```

instead. How can I achieve what I want ?

EDIT: I double checked (it's morning here, and I'm not really awake), this seems to be a [VC8 bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/101539/valid-c-template-code-that-compiled-under-vs-2003-doesnt-compile-in-vs-2005):

Comment: Seems to work on my machine. Same compiler though.

Comment: I copy pasted the exact code above, no includes, and I copy pasted the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All restrictions for friend of a class or class template are described in section `14.5.3` of the C++ Standard. Your code is valid. Check you have installed all latest service packs for the Visual Studio. [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=C3855) you can find related bugs in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you, it seems indeed to be a VC8 bug. Unfortunately, I cannot change the compiler, so I'll go with public members.

Comment: [This](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/262353/compile-error-when-making-a-template-class-a-friend-of-itself-works-on-vc7-1-and-gcc-3-4-4#details) bug is very likely the same issue. Consider installing service pack for VC8.